# Moving website from Windows localhost to Linux live server: issues with filenames and paths

Tags: php, linux, url, web, server

I am moving my site to a live server and I found out in the process that linux servers are case sensitive, so it is not a good idea to have URLs with capital letters.

Is that also important for filenames?

All my classes start with capital letter which makes it easier to navigate through files.

Should I change all files to lowercase?

Comment: apache mod_speling may solve your problem....

Comment: File system conventions are indeed case sensitive on most file systems. Not even sure if there is any other exception besides MS-Windows. But that has little to do with class names. Camel case class naming schemes certainly do make sense. Also I do not see any real reason why capital letter in a URL should be a problem, except for the leading host name itself. It certainly saves you trouble if you change all file names to lowercase, yes, but that's about it...

Comment: The other exception is HFS+, the default filesystem on OS X, which is case-insensitive (but case-preserving) by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change file names, just be consistent i.e use the file names as it is in your PHP Code. If your class name is `Post` stick with `Post` in the php code and not `post`, In fact Capital letter in the beginning of the class name is common standard which should be followed(just for readability, no strict rule).

File path will be an issue if you have hard-coded the path like `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysite` anywhere in your project. **Avoid** that. Use relative path, `__FILE__` and/or `__DIR__` instead.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Same goes for URL, **avoid** using `http://localhost` in the code. You can set the base url in the beginning of your project where you can write something like :

```
if(defined('DEV')){
  $url = "http://localhost/mysite";
} 
elseif(defined('PROD')){
  $url = "http://example.com"
}
```

If you are using any php framework, you can use their global variable to access base url and ignore above code.

In windows desktop environment(not Server), apache's process is generally same user as the owner of the files. So hardly anyone faces any issues regarding permission in Windows. While in linux, see to it all files have proper permission. Generally people find issues with `images` folder. Change its permission according to your need.
https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/309527-understanding-linux-file-permissions